# How to use __main__ as the setuptools's entry points

Tags: python, setuptools

If the cli file is like below, how to set it as the setuptools's enter points?

```
project_root_directory
├── setup.py
└── file1.py

file1.py
def detect():
  ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  ...
  opt = parser.parse_args()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refactor `file1.py` this way:

```py
def detect():
  ...

def main():
  parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
  opt = parser.parse_args()
  ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

and use `file1:main` as the entry point.